# How to change some path value with regular expression?

Tags: jquery, regex

I have 2 href inside my links:

```
http://localhost:60013/Home/GetJobsByPageAjax?page=1&class=active&profId=4&IsJob=False&IsResume=True

http://localhost:60013/Home/GetJobsByPageAjax?page=1&class=active&IsJob=False&IsResume=False
```

I need to replace IsJob, IsResume from False to True and with return. I need to do this with jquery. I don't want to do this with concatenation or split, know this is can do with regular expression, but dont know how. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use this.

```
url.replace(/(IsJob|IsResume)=False/g, "$1=True")
```

Or, to replace any `=False`,

```
url.replace(/(\w+)=False/g, "$1=True");
```

And to automatically call it on all links (the second method, you can probably work out how to use the other here):

```
$("a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href").replace(/(\w+)=False/g, "$1=True"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:60013/Home/GetJobsByPageAjax?page=1&class=active&profId=4&IsJob=False&IsResume=True';

url.replace(/(Is(Job|Resume))=False/g, '$1=True');
```